# Store non-unique pairs in .net 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I have to store a pair of strings that are non-unique, so I could have something like:

`"A", "B"` 
`"A","C"`

I can't use a Dictionary or HashTable because I don't have a unique key. I thought about a couple options:

```
List<List<string>,List<string>> = new List<List<string>,List<string>>(); //Too long?
```

Create a class or struct (what is better?) to hold my pairs and then store that in list, so

```
class pairs
{

}

List<pairs> values = new List<pairs>();
```

I also just need to be able to enumerate through the pairs, so I don't need care about querying, sorting, comparing. Because of this, is it best to use the least specific type, such as Enumerable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structs by themselves don't require unique keys, even if you collect them in a single list.

If you think KVPs don't ring well semantically with what you want, just go with a custom type. It shouldn't matter whether your custom type is a class or struct.

Comment: I actually forgot about KeyValuePair.  Excellent suggestion.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion about using the least specific type?

Comment: @Xaisoft: I don't know what you mean by least specific type.

Comment: @BoltClock, my specific value/reference type, I meant, the type is just enough to get the job done. For example,  if I know I just need an int or string, I will declare a variable and int or string and not an object.  The same applies for reference types.

Answer (score 2):

What about just a `List<string[]>`?

```
var list = new List<string[]>();

list.Add(new [] { "A", "B"});

foreach(var pair in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(pair[0] + pair[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, why didn't I think of this... it even saves a bunch of keystrokes as a bonus!

Comment: @scottm,  What is the advantage/disadvantage between BoltClock's solution.

Comment: @Xaisoft, The KeyValuePair is a struct (value type), so if there will be lots of passing these pairs around you'll have to copy the values in memory.

Comment: An array containing 2 strings would practically the same in terms of what is being passed around.  The problem I have with the array approach (though admittedly good) is that there is no requirement that there only be 2 items per array.  It is nice when the data type implies its use, it makes the code more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`, but to avoid the semantics of a key (since you said it wasn't unique), I would use a `List<Tuple<string,string>>` which is practically the same but with different semantics.

Comment: Except the built-in `Tuple` type is only available in .NET 4.

Comment: KeyValuePair is a struct, while Tuple is a class. Most applications shouldn't need to care about the difference, but it may have an effect on memory usage and the garbage collector.

Comment: Ah yes framework versions.  I had the same question (how to store a logical pair that wasn't a Key/Value) until I found the Tuple<T1,T2> generic.  The semantics of it are just right since it implies they are related but not a Key/Value.   I agree that creating a custom type (like reimplementing Tuple<T1,T2> for use with .NET 2.0) doesn't feel right either.